# Getting Oops on *_fill_super

Tags: oop, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel-module

friends!

I have a problem with compiling modules for prebuilt kernel.
The problem is - compiled modules fails with Oops near "fill_super" function.

1. compile modules - OK
2. insmod modules - OK
3. Try to mount filesystem (ntfs/ext2/ext3/ext4) - got Oops :(

Sample trace here

```
Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000008
pgd = c39e8000
[00000008] *pgd=83a72831, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 17 [#2]
Modules linked in: ntfs ext3 jbd crc16 scsi_wait_scan hi3520D_adec(P) hi3520D_aenc(P) hi3520D_ao(P) hi3520D_ai(P) hi3520D_sio(P) hiwdt hi_ir hi_rtc fvideo gpioi2c hi3520D_hdmi(P) hi3520D_vfmw(P) hi3520D_vdec(P) hifb(P) vcmp(P) hi3520D_region(P) hi3520D_vpss(P) hi3520D_vou(P) hi3520D_viu(P) hi3520D_rc(P) hi3520D_h264e(P) hi3520D_chnl(P) hi3520D_group(P) hi3520D_venc(P) hi3520D_dsu(P) hi3520D_tde(P) hi3520D_sys(P) hi3520D_base(P) hiuser mmz
CPU: 0    Tainted: P      D      (3.0.8 #6)
PC is at __find_get_block_slow+0x10/0x13c
LR is at __find_get_block+0xec/0x500
pc : [<c00bb3a8>]    lr : [<c00bb934>]    psr: 68000013
sp : c39b5ca4  ip : c39b5cd4  fp : c39b5cd0
r10: 00000100  r9 : c39d3000  r8 : c39d3000
r7 : 00000000  r6 : 00000400  r5 : c03d2830  r4 : c53acb00
r3 : 00000100  r2 : 00000400  r1 : 00000000  r0 : 00000000
Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 10c53c7d  Table: 839e8059  DAC: 00000015

PC: 0xc00bb328:
b328  e1a0c00d e92dd800 e24cb004 e5903000 e3130a02 13a00001 189da800 e30a0f14
b348  e34c0030 ebfde5bb e2700001 33a00000 e89da800 e1a0c00d e92dd810 e24cb004
b368  e24dd024 e1a04000 e24b1034 e5900020 eb009372 e1c421d0 e1a01000 e30309a8
b388  e34c0038 eb0924df e24bd010 e89da810 e1a0c00d e92ddbf0 e24cb004 e24dd008
b3a8  e5905008 e1a09003 e1a08002 e595e064 e59500b0 e26e400c e2641020 e1a0c432
b3c8  e18c2113 e2543020 41a01002 51a01339 ebfec239 e2504000 01a06004 0a000018
b3e8  e5940000 e3100b02 0a000012 e5946000 e3160b02 0a000030 e594700c e3a01001
b408  e1a06007 e5963000 e2132020 01a01002 0a000003 e1c621d0 e1530009 01520008

LR: 0xc00bb8b4:
b8b4  0a0000ae e5951014 e3510000 0a000002 e591c020 e150000c 0a0000b2 e5951018
b8d4  e3510000 0a000002 e591c020 e150000c 0a0000b6 e595101c e3510000 0a000002
b8f4  e591c020 e150000c 0a0000ba e5951020 e3510000 0a000002 e591c020 e150000c
b914  0a00008c e5951024 e3510000 0a000002 e5914020 e1500004 0a0000b8 ebfffe98
b934  e2504000 0a000076 e10f2000 e3120080 1a0000fa e5951008 e3023830 e34c303d
b954  e1540001 0a00006c e284e038 e19ecf9f e28cc001 e18e1f9c e3310000 1afffffa
b974  e593c008 e50b403c e154000c 150bc038 13a06002 0a0000da e595300c e1540003
b994  0a0000d4 e24b001c e0802106 e2866001 e5023020 e5953010 e1540003 0a0000dc

SP: 0xc39b5c24:
5c24  c39b5c40 c39b5c34 c00485ec c39b5cb8 c39b4000 ffffffff c39b5c8c 00000400
5c44  00000000 c39b5cd0 c39b5c58 c0024d8c c0024250 00000000 00000000 00000400
5c64  00000100 c53acb00 c03d2830 00000400 00000000 c39d3000 c39d3000 00000100
5c84  c39b5cd0 c39b5cd4 c39b5ca4 c00bb934 c00bb3a8 68000013 ffffffff 00000002
5ca4  c39b5e47 0000000a c53acb00 c03d2830 00000400 00000000 c39d3000 c39d3000
5cc4  c39b5d10 c39b5cd4 c00bb934 c00bb3a4 0000000a 0000ffff c39b5e64 0000ffff
5ce4  c39b5d90 c39b5cf4 c01909c0 c01903ac c53acb00 00000000 00000400 00000000
5d04  c39b5d78 c39b5d14 c00bbd70 c00bb854 00000000 00000000 c5c03c40 c39ed000

IP: 0xc39b5c54:
5c54  c0024250 00000000 00000000 00000400 00000100 c53acb00 c03d2830 00000400
5c74  00000000 c39d3000 c39d3000 00000100 c39b5cd0 c39b5cd4 c39b5ca4 c00bb934
5c94  c00bb3a8 68000013 ffffffff 00000002 c39b5e47 0000000a c53acb00 c03d2830
5cb4  00000400 00000000 c39d3000 c39d3000 c39b5d10 c39b5cd4 c00bb934 c00bb3a4
5cd4  0000000a 0000ffff c39b5e64 0000ffff c39b5d90 c39b5cf4 c01909c0 c01903ac
5cf4  c53acb00 00000000 00000400 00000000 c39b5d78 c39b5d14 c00bbd70 c00bb854
5d14  00000000 00000000 c5c03c40 c39ed000 00000400 00000000 c00c3264 c006d8d8
5d34  c39b5d50 c39b5d44 0000000a c5c03c40 c39b5d70 c39b5d54 c00c3f9c c53acb00

FP: 0xc39b5c50:
5c50  c0024d8c c0024250 00000000 00000000 00000400 00000100 c53acb00 c03d2830
5c70  00000400 00000000 c39d3000 c39d3000 00000100 c39b5cd0 c39b5cd4 c39b5ca4
5c90  c00bb934 c00bb3a8 68000013 ffffffff 00000002 c39b5e47 0000000a c53acb00
5cb0  c03d2830 00000400 00000000 c39d3000 c39d3000 c39b5d10 c39b5cd4 c00bb934
5cd0  c00bb3a4 0000000a 0000ffff c39b5e64 0000ffff c39b5d90 c39b5cf4 c01909c0
5cf0  c01903ac c53acb00 00000000 00000400 00000000 c39b5d78 c39b5d14 c00bbd70
5d10  c00bb854 00000000 00000000 c5c03c40 c39ed000 00000400 00000000 c00c3264
5d30  c006d8d8 c39b5d50 c39b5d44 0000000a c5c03c40 c39b5d70 c39b5d54 c00c3f9c

R4: 0xc53aca80:
ca80  c04b0b60 c04b0b80 c04b0ba0 c04b0bc0 c04b0be0 c04b0c00 c04b0c20 c04b0c40
caa0  c04b0c60 c04b0c80 c04b0ca0 c04b0cc0 c04b0ce0 c04b0d00 c04b0d20 c04b0d40
cac0  c04b0d60 c04b0d80 c04b0da0 c04b0dc0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
cae0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
cb00  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
cb20  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
cb40  00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
cb60  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

R5: 0xc03d27b0:
27b0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
27d0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
27f0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000001 c03a31a8
2810  00000023 00000032 00000012 00000000 c6180780 c5c02280 c6180780 c5c02280
2830  000013b9 000006fa 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
2850  00000000 00000000 00000001 c03d285c c03d285c 00000200 c03d2868 c03d2868
2870  c00c0978 c5cad214 c5c03214 c0383894 00000000 c00c2fd0 c00972c0 00000000
2890  c03d2a88 c6003490 c6003490 c03d289c c03d289c c612ff80 c612ff80 c00c905c

R8: 0xc39d2f80:
2f80  746f6e2e 6e672e65 75622e75 2d646c69 ff006469 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
2fa0  6d79732e 00626174 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
2fc0  7274732e 00626174 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
2fe0  74636573 736e6f69 ffffff00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
3000  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000061 0000e0a5 00000003 00c1c540 00c1d540
3020  00c1c540 00c1c540 00c1c540 00c1c540 000b0850 00c1c4e4 0004f8b8 0004f8b0
3040  0004f884 0004f87c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002 00000000
3060  00000000 00000000 00000000 00001009 65646f6e 79730976 0a736673 65646f6e

R9: 0xc39d2f80:
2f80  746f6e2e 6e672e65 75622e75 2d646c69 ff006469 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
2fa0  6d79732e 00626174 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
2fc0  7274732e 00626174 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
2fe0  74636573 736e6f69 ffffff00 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
3000  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000061 0000e0a5 00000003 00c1c540 00c1d540
3020  00c1c540 00c1c540 00c1c540 00c1c540 000b0850 00c1c4e4 0004f8b8 0004f8b0
3040  0004f884 0004f87c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002 00000000
3060  00000000 00000000 00000000 00001009 65646f6e 79730976 0a736673 65646f6e
Process mount (pid: 790, stack limit = 0xc39b4268)
Stack: (0xc39b5ca4 to 0xc39b6000)
5ca0:          c39b5e47 0000000a c53acb00 c03d2830 00000400 00000000 c39d3000
5cc0: c39d3000 c39b5d10 c39b5cd4 c00bb934 c00bb3a4 0000000a 0000ffff c39b5e64
5ce0: 0000ffff c39b5d90 c39b5cf4 c01909c0 c01903ac c53acb00 00000000 00000400
5d00: 00000000 c39b5d78 c39b5d14 c00bbd70 c00bb854 00000000 00000000 c5c03c40
5d20: c39ed000 00000400 00000000 c00c3264 c006d8d8 c39b5d50 c39b5d44 0000000a
5d40: c5c03c40 c39b5d70 c39b5d54 c00c3f9c c53acb00 c39ed000 00000400 00000000
5d60: c39d3000 c39d3000 00000001 c39b5d98 c39b5d7c c00bfd60 c00bbd54 00000000
5d80: c39b5d8c c00c403c c53acb00 c39b5e40 c39b5d9c bf3ee6c8 c00bfd50 00000000
5da0: c39b5db4 bf3f5a10 00000001 c0318714 c39b5e44 ff0a0210 ffffffff c39b5e20
5dc0: c39b5e44 00000002 c534cc00 c534cc0c c39ed000 c39d3000 c39d3000 c39b5e00
5de0: c39b5dec c019322c 00000001 c0096838 c39b5e08 c39b5e30 c39b5e0c c00e0120
5e00: c0193218 c03853cc c39ed14c c39d3000 00000000 00000000 c5c03c40 00000083
5e20: c5c03ca4 00008000 c39ed000 c39d3000 c39d3000 c39b5e88 c39b5e44 c0097a80
5e40: bf3ee5e8 32616473 c39b5e00 c0091ccc c39cd250 00000000 c39b5e84 c39b5e68
5e60: c0092a78 c39cd1e0 bf3f5a10 bf3f5a10 00008000 c39d3000 c39b5f38 c39b5e9c
5e80: c39b5e8c bf3eca7c c009792c bf3ee5dc c39b5ecc c39b5ea0 c0096888 bf3eca68
5ea0: c00aea60 c007cde0 bf3f5a10 c39cd1e0 bf3f5a10 c39ff9e0 c39d3000 c39d3000
5ec0: c39b5ef4 c39b5ed0 c00b02f8 c0096878 c39d3000 bf3f5a10 c39ffaa0 c39d3000
5ee0: c39ff9e0 00008000 c39b5f1c c39b5ef8 c00b038c c00b02ac c39d3000 00000000
5f00: c39ff9e0 00000020 c39ffaa0 00008000 c39b5f6c c39b5f20 c00b057c c00b035c
5f20: c39b4000 00008000 c39b5f44 c39b5f38 c0074058 c00739d0 c6180780 c5cbf800
5f40: c00af2c8 c56bf000 befd6f59 00000000 00008000 c0025324 c39b4000 00000000
5f60: c39b5fa4 c39b5f70 c00b0b98 c00b0430 c39d3000 00000000 fe300100 c39d3000
5f80: c39ff9e0 c39ffaa0 00c1c4d0 00c1c4d0 befd6f59 00000015 00000000 c39b5fa8
5fa0: c00251a0 c00b0b18 00c1c4d0 00c1c4d0 befd6f59 befd6f63 00c1d750 00008000
5fc0: 00c1c4d0 00c1c4d0 befd6f59 00000015 befd6f63 00c1c4e0 00c1d750 0006bcc8
5fe0: 00c1c498 befd6af4 00020618 000425e0 60000010 befd6f59 00000000 00000000
Backtrace: 
[<c00bb398>] (__find_get_block_slow+0x0/0x13c) from [<c00bb934>] (__find_get_block+0xec/0x500)
 r9:c39d3000 r8:c39d3000 r7:00000000 r6:00000400 r5:c03d2830
r4:c53acb00
[<c00bb848>] (__find_get_block+0x0/0x500) from [<c00bbd70>] (__getblk+0x28/0x2fc)
 r7:00000000 r6:00000400 r5:00000000 r4:c53acb00
[<c00bbd48>] (__getblk+0x0/0x2fc) from [<c00bfd60>] (__bread+0x1c/0xdc)
[<c00bfd44>] (__bread+0x0/0xdc) from [<bf3ee6c8>] (ext3_fill_super+0xec/0x1734 [ext3])
 r4:c53acb00
[<bf3ee5dc>] (ext3_fill_super+0x0/0x1734 [ext3]) from [<c0097a80>] (mount_bdev+0x160/0x18c)
[<c0097920>] (mount_bdev+0x0/0x18c) from [<bf3eca7c>] (ext3_mount+0x20/0x24 [ext3])
[<bf3eca5c>] (ext3_mount+0x0/0x24 [ext3]) from [<c0096888>] (mount_fs+0x1c/0xe0)
[<c009686c>] (mount_fs+0x0/0xe0) from [<c00b02f8>] (vfs_kern_mount+0x58/0x90)
 r9:c39d3000 r8:c39d3000 r6:c39ff9e0 r5:bf3f5a10 r4:c39cd1e0
[<c00b02a0>] (vfs_kern_mount+0x0/0x90) from [<c00b038c>] (do_kern_mount+0x3c/0xd4)
 r8:00008000 r7:c39ff9e0 r6:c39d3000 r5:c39ffaa0 r4:bf3f5a10
r3:c39d3000
[<c00b0350>] (do_kern_mount+0x0/0xd4) from [<c00b057c>] (do_mount+0x158/0x6e8)
 r8:00008000 r7:c39ffaa0 r6:00000020 r5:c39ff9e0 r4:00000000
r3:c39d3000
[<c00b0424>] (do_mount+0x0/0x6e8) from [<c00b0b98>] (sys_mount+0x8c/0xcc)
[<c00b0b0c>] (sys_mount+0x0/0xcc) from [<c00251a0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
 r7:00000015 r6:befd6f59 r5:00c1c4d0 r4:00c1c4d0
Code: e1a0c00d e92ddbf0 e24cb004 e24dd008 (e5905008) 
---[ end trace b62a4323b2714208 ]---
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I found than sb->s_bdev field in superblock structure is NULL. So this is a reason. But I don't know why its always NULL.

Comment: Can you pls tell the exact mount command you used in step 3?